# support URL while uploading the app

Tags: iphone, ios

What should be the support URL while uploading the app on itunes? It is giving the warninig to fill the support url but I don't have the any idea about it. Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: it should be link to support page of your website where your app users can check you support email, support phone, FAQs about your app or can fill up form to report any bug/problem in your app. E.g. http://flipboard.com/support

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The support URL should point to a website that you made to give support for your app. You can just make a quick website that is essentially a placeholder for your future support site but they want something or maybe just use a free blog where you give support information for your app. It doesn't have to be great for them to accept it.

Comment: My first app support website was through blogspot, then I did it through mobile me, now I am actually hosting it through DropBox and using a co.nr redirection.  There are ways to get a decent website for absolutely no cost whatsoever.